# Unable to instantiate activity componentInfo, null pointer exception

Tags: android, xml, nullpointerexception, android-activity

I am building a game and essentially what I am trying to do is to parse an XML file to the following two purposes:

1. load files from assets
2. instantiate sprite classes with the corresponding data

Then, load the sprites for the selected scene into a list and pass it for rendering (which is done in a different thread). Behaviour for the sprites will be added later.

Here is the code I am using:

```java
public class SceneMngr extends Activity implements OnGestureListener{

MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
SoundPool soundpool;
WakeLock wakeLock;
List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
List<Node> sceneItems = new ArrayList<Node>();
int i,j,q;
AssetManager assMan = getAssets();
Map <String, Integer> soundPoolMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
Map <String, Bitmap> imageMap = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>(); 
Loader loader = new Loader();
private GestureDetector gDetector;
ArrayList<Sprite> sprites ;
FastRenderView renderView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Lock");
    wakeLock.acquire();
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
    soundpool = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    renderView = new FastRenderView(this);
    setContentView(renderView);     
    renderView.resume();

    loadAssets();
    loadScene("mainMenu");
}   

public void loadAssets(){
    nodes = loader.readAssets();

        if (nodes.get(nodes.size()-1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("type").getNodeValue().equals("image") ){
            try{
            InputStream is =  assMan.open(nodes.get(nodes.size()-1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue());
             imageMap.put(nodes.get(nodes.size()-1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue(), BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));
            is.close();}
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
        if (nodes.get(nodes.size()-1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("type").getNodeValue().equals("sound") ){
            try{
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = assMan.openFd(nodes.get(nodes.size()-1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue());
             soundPoolMap.put(nodes.get(nodes.size()-1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue(), soundpool.load(descriptor, 1));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
        if (nodes.get(nodes.size()-1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("type").getNodeValue().equals("music") ){
             try {
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor2 = assMan.openFd(nodes.get(nodes.size()-1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue());
mediaplayer.setDataSource(descriptor2.getFileDescriptor(),
         descriptor2.getStartOffset(), descriptor2.getLength());
mediaplayer.prepare();
mediaplayer.setLooping(true);
mediaplayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
mediaplayer.start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                mediaplayer = null;
            }
        }
 }


public void loadScene(String sceneId){
    sceneItems=loader.readScene(sceneId);
    String[] temp = new String[3];
    sprites.clear();        //dispose previous scene: empty sprite list

    //create a sprite for each node 
    for (i=0; i <sceneItems.size(); i++){
        for (j=0; j < 2; j++){
            temp[j] = sceneItems.get(i).getAttributes().item(j).getNodeValue();
            }
        sprites.add(new Sprite(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2])); 
        }
    }

class FastRenderView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    Thread renderThread = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    volatile boolean running = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
        return gDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
    }


    public FastRenderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder=getHolder();
    }

    public void resume() {
        running = true;
        renderThread = new Thread(this);
        renderThread.start();
        }

    public void pause() {        
        running = false;                        
        while(true) {
            try {
                renderThread.join();
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // retry
            }
        }
        renderThread = null;        
    }

    public void run() {
        while(running) {
        if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
        continue;
        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        drawSurfice(canvas);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    private void drawSurfice(Canvas canvas){
        for (q=0; q < sprites.size(); q++){
           if (sprites.get(q).visibilitySwitch.equals("true")){
             canvas.drawBitmap(imageMap.get(sprites.get(q).srcImg), sprites.get(q).src, sprites.get(q).dst, null);
            }
        }
    }   
 }

public class Loader{

    int h,k,t;
    SoundPool soundpool;
    AssetManager assMan = getAssets();
    MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
    List<Node> assetList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    List<Node> spriteList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    List<Node> sceneItems = new ArrayList<Node>();
    Document doc;
    Map <String, Integer> soundPoolMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
    Map <String, Bitmap> imageMap = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>(); 

    public Loader(){

        }

    //load items of targeted scene into a list
    public List<Node> readScene(String sceneId){
        for (h = 0; h < doc.getElementsByTagName("scene").getLength(); h++){ 
            if (doc.getElementsByTagName("scene").item(h).getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue().equals(sceneId)){
                for (t=0; t< doc.getElementsByTagName("scene").item(h).getChildNodes().getLength(); t++ )
                    if (doc.getElementsByTagName("scene").item(h).getChildNodes().item(t).getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE)
 sceneItems.add(doc.getElementsByTagName("scene").item(h).getChildNodes().item(t));
            }
        }
        return sceneItems;
     }

    public List<Node> readAssets(){
            //load asset file
        try {
            InputStream inStream = assMan.open("assetss.xml");
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse(inStream);
            inStream.close();       
        }catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
            //create list of asset items 
        for ( k = 0; k <  doc.getElementsByTagName("assets").item(0).getChildNodes().getLength(); k++ ){
            if (doc.getElementsByTagName("assets").item(0).getChildNodes().item(k).getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE){
                assetList.add(doc.getElementsByTagName("assets").item(0).getChildNodes().item(k));}
                }
         return assetList;
    }
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
}    

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    return true;
}

}


public class Sprite {
public Bitmap img;
public String soundfx;
Rect src = new Rect();
Rect dst = new Rect();
String visibilitySwitch, srcImg;
    List<Integer> posList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public Sprite (String image, String position, String visibility){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(position); 

    while (m.find()) {
           int n = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
           posList.add(n);
        }

    src.set(posList.get(0), posList.get(1), posList.get(2), posList.get(3));
    dst.set(posList.get(4), posList.get(5), posList.get(6), posList.get(7));
         visibilitySwitch=visibility;
    srcImg= image;
         }
}
```

and here is the test XML file I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>

<assets>
<sprite src="menuitems.png" name="menu" type="image"/>
<sprite src="buttons.png" name="buttons" type="image"/>
<sprite src="animals.png" name="animals" type="image"/>
<sprite src="music.mp3" name="music" type="sound"/>
<sprite src="click.ogg" name="clickSound" type="sound"/>
<sprite src="swipe.ogg" name="swipeSound" type="sound"/>
<sprite src="dog.mp3" name="dog" type="sound"/>
<sprite src="cow.mp3" name="cow" type="sound"/>
<sprite src="horse.mp3" name="horse" type="sound"/>
<sprite src="bunny.mp3" name="bunny" type="sound"/>
<sprite src="munubackground.png" name="menubackground" type="image"/>
</assets>

<scene id="mainMenu">
<sprite src="menuitems.png" position="0 0 192 42 100 100 292 142" visibility="true"/>
</scene>

<scene id="game">
<sprite src="background.jpg" position="0 0 0 0 0 0 200 200" visibility="true" name="background"   />
<sprite src="menu.jpg" position="0 0 0 0 100 100 200 200" visibility="true" name="playButton"  audio="click.ogg" onClick="playSound, nextScene"/>
<sprite src="menu.jpg" position="100 100 100 100 100 100 200 200" visibility="true" name="settingsButton"  audio="click.ogg" onclick="playSound, nextScene"/>
<sprite src="menu.jpg" position="100 100 100 100 100 100 200 200" visibility="true" name="helpButton"  audio="click.ogg" onclick="playSound, nextScene"/>
</scene>
</xml>
```

I am getting the following error from logcat:

```
04-23 05:24:15.198: D/AndroidRuntime(1919): Shutting down VM
04-23 05:24:15.198: W/dalvikvm(1919): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a4aba8)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919): Process: com.test.farm, PID: 1919
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test.farm/com.test.farm.SceneMngr}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:83)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at com.test.farm.SceneMngr.<init>(SceneMngr.java:42)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
04-23 05:24:15.208: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     ... 11 more
```

and the manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.farm"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
  <activity android:name=".SceneMngr"
            android:label="SceneManager"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
  </activity>    



</application>

</manifest>
```

Any idea(s) what is causing this error? I have tried the code part by part in the console and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference `Context` until `onCreate()` is called, so you should assign `AssetManager` in `onCreate()`.

```
private AssetManager assMan;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    assMan = getAssets();
```

Also you have other problems here, `WakeLock` is not released and not needed for your purpose at all. Instead, use `keepScreenOn` attrubute of a `View`. This doesn't require a `WAKE_LOCK` permission.

```
public FastRenderView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setKeepScreenOn(true);
    holder=getHolder();
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right about the wakelock, I changed it but that was not causing error since I have used it before without any problems. The error had to do with the asset manager indeed. But now I am getting another similar error:04-23 07:00:18.018: E/AndroidRuntime(2164): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.farm/com.test.farm.SceneMngr}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @user3433393 we are not extraterestrials to help you without you updating the question with new stacktrace and line pointing.

Answer (score -1):

you should call getAssets() in activity.oncreate()

Comment: That is what I am currently doing

Comment: You are right, Sorry I though you were reffering to the readAssets method.